# Can I use a LatLng object as a double?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, double

I am in an awkward spot where I *need* to use a LatLng object into a double. Please help me out. Just to clarify this now: I can not use 2 variables instead of 1 due to other parts of my code.

Here's the code:

```
protected LatLng end;

Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
    Address add = list.get(0);
    String addressline = add.getAddressLine(0);
    Toast.makeText(this, addressline, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    end = new LatLng(add.getLatitude(), add.getLongitude());

    gotoLocation(end, DEFAULTZOOM);

    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(end));
    marker = mMap.addMarker(options);

    if (marker != null) {
        marker.remove();
    }
}
```

gotoLocation code:

```
private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng,
                              float zoom) {
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
        mMap.moveCamera(update);
        mMap.animateCamera(update);
    }
```

The problem is if I make `end` a double then it gives an error on this line- `end = new LatLng(add.getLatitude(), add.getLongitude());` saying it expected a LatLng object. When I make it a LatLng object the line `gotoLocation(end, DEFAULTZOOM);` get an error telling me- Wrong 1st argument type(basically it found a LatLng object instead of a double).

Thank you for reading all the way through!

Comment: what does `gotoLocation` do. post the code

Comment: LatLng is not a double, the latitude or longitude value is but together it is impossible to make that into a double

Comment: It is not possible to store a paired coordinate as a single value.

Comment: @tyczj is there any workaround then?

Comment: You can avoid sending the end object. Simply call the method gotoLocation(add.getLatitude(), add.getLongitude(), DEFAULTZOOM);

Or, change the signature of the method gotoLocation to accept a LatLng object, instead of two doubles object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you just change the `gotoLocation` to accept a LatLng object

```
private void gotoLocation(LatLng ll,float zoom) {
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
    mMap.moveCamera(update);
    mMap.animateCamera(update);
}
```

Comment: `options.position` still gets an error because it expects 2 doubles. How do I fix this?

Comment: you already have a latlng object (end) why are you trying to create another one just use that. you should look at the documentation and see how to use the constructor for LatLng or maybe even buy a programming book because this is basic stuff that you are having trouble with